# Regex for Date in format dd.MM.yyyy?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Trying to create a `regex` for Date in this format `dd.MM.yyyy`.

I want to use it with a `DataAnnotation`, like this

```
[RegularExpression(@"<theregex>")]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

Comment: Does it have to take into account invalid dates like 30.02.2010 and things like that or is it just something to pull out things that look like dates and you can then check them afterwards?

Comment: Why do you need a regex? Would it not be better to use `Date.ParseExact()`?

Comment: @Rowland Shaw I use xVal which is generating rules for jquery.validation

Comment: It's smarter to use date.parse or yyyy.mm.dd. If someone from the u.s. saw that date format, they would try 02.30.2010...

Comment: @Rowland: Date.ParseExact() is no valid value for a data annotation. These need to be constant.

Comment: @Jens that wasn't mentioned up front

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest that regex is not exactly the best way to do this. You haven't given the context, so it's hard to guess what you're doing overall... but you might want to create a `DateExpression` attribute or such and then do:

```
return DateTime.ParseExact(value, "dd.MM.yyyy");
```

in wherever your converter is defined.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I get `No overload for method 'ParseExact' takes 2 arguments`

Answer (score 4):

```
^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[.](0[1-9]|1[012])[.](19|20)[0-9]{2}$
```

This regex matches `01.01.1900`, `01.01.2000` but doesn't match `1.1.2000` or `1/1/00`.

Comment: you could at least make the 0's optional... it also doesn't match 31.01.2000 :(

Comment: Surely it will match 31.01.2000?

Comment: But it will break in the next millennium :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
[0-3]{0,1}[0-9]\.[0-1]{0,1}[0-9]\.[0-9]{4,2}
```

matches:
`28.2.96`, `1.11.2008` and `12.10.2005`

Answer (score 1):

Just because I always find this site useful, here is an [online regex checker](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/). On the right hand side it also has examples and community contributions. In there are a number of Date matching regex variations.

You can type in a load of dates you wish to match and try some of the different examples if you're not sure which is best for you. As with anything, there are multiple ways to solve the problem, but it might help you choose the one that fits best.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$
```

This one also accepts - and / as separators. You can remove them if you want.