# Can my Regex be improved?

Tags: c#, regex, validation

Yes, *another* Regex question. You're welcome ;-P

This is the first time I've written my own regex for some simple string validation in C#. I think I've got it working but as a learning exercise I was wondering if it could be improved and whether I have made any mistakes.

The strings will all look something like this:

> T20160307.0001

Rules:

- Begin with the letter T.
- Date in the format YYYYMMDD.
- A full stop.
- Last 4 characters are always numeric. There should be exactly 4.

Here is my regex ([fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/fY9bZ3/3)):

> ^(?i)[T]20[0-9]{2}[0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9].\d{4}$

- `^` Assert the start of the string.
- `(?i)[T]` Check that we have a letter T, case insensitive.
- `20` YYYY begins with 20 (I'll be dead by 2100 so I don't care about anything further :-P)
- `[0-9]{2}` Any number between 0 and 99 for second part of YYYY.
- `[0-1][0-9]` 0 or 1 for first part of month, 0-9 for second part of month.
- `[0-3][0-9]` 0-3 for first part of day, 0-9 for second part of day.
- `.` Full stop.
- `\d{4}` 4 numerical characters.
- `$` Assert end of string.

One pitfall I can already see is date validation. 20161935 (the 35th day of the 19th month) is considered valid. I've read [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359188/c-sharp-regular-expression-to-validate-a-date) / [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16814871/regex-specific-date-format) / [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156128/regex-for-date-in-format-dd-mm-yyyy) about achieving this which I believe match on number ranges but I was unable to understand the format.

I would accept an answer that simply solved the date issue if someone would be kind enough to ELI5 how this works, but other improvements would be a welcome bonus.

**Edit:** To avoid further confusion I should state that I know about DateTime.TryParse etc. As mentioned I'm using this as an opportunity to learn Regex and felt this was a good starting point. Sorry to anyone who's time I wasted, I should have made this clear in the original post.

Comment: You have a good start. The dot needs to be escaped: `\.`, or it will match any character. I would suggest the following improvements: `(?i)T` -> `[Tt]` (it's shorter, and I'm not sure it `(?i)` is allowed inline); use consistently either `[0-9]` or `\d`. I would suggest to validate the date outside the regex, since leap year rules are complicated and your regex will get messy.

Comment: Why not use the DateTime.Tryparse and let this handle if the date is valid. simpler , and if youre format / requiremend changes more easy to adjust! Also how will you handle a leap year in youre regex?

Comment: Related, for validating the date: [Wanted: DateTime.TryNew(year, month, day) or DateTime.IsValidDate(year, month, day)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9467967/87698)

Comment: @Heinzi, that one's overkill, all you need is `DateTime.TryParseExact` with the `yyyyMMdd` format on the captured substring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why even use Regex just use the [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) Method. I'd implement it like so with extra checks for the other characters:

```
bool IsCorrectFormat(string input)
{
    //14 is a magic number for the length of the expected format
    if (input.Length == 14 && input.StartsWith("T", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        DateTime dt;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input.Substring(1), "yyyyMMdd.ffff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I don't know if the format is correct but you could always substring from 1 to 6 to get the `yyyyMMdd` then check for a decimal point and numerics at the last 5 characters.

EDIT: If this must be done with regex

I have used this regex in the past. Note that it does not check for leap years

```
@"^(((0[1-9]{1}|[1-2][0-9]{1}|3[01]{1})(0[13578]{1}|1[12]{1}))" //For a 31 day month
+ @"|"
+ @"((0[1-9]{1}|[1-2][0-9]{1}|30)(0[469]{1}|11))" //For a 30 day month
+ @"|"
+ @"((0[1-9]{1}|1[0-9]{1}|2[0-8]{1})(02)))" //For a 28 day month(feb)
+ @"([0-9]{4})$"; //For the year
```

Comment: The answers are all brilliant but I feel this one is the best fit for what I asked. Thanks all.

Answer (score 4):

The things you can do are:

- avoid the `\d` character class that matches all the unicode digits (since you only need the ascii digits)
- instead of `[0-1]` you can write `[01]`
- escape the dot to figure a literal dot (and not any characters)
- no need to put `T` in a character class if it is the only character
- eventually you can remove the inline modifier and use `[Tt]` in place of `T`

```
^(?i)T20[0-9]{2}[01][0-9][0-3][0-9]\.[0-9]{4}$
```

or

```
^[Tt]20[0-9]{2}[01][0-9][0-3][0-9]\.[0-9]{4}$
```

Other thing: do you really need to add extra checking for the date since you can't really test if the date is well formatted? (Think a minute about leap years) So why not:

```
^(?i)T(20[0-9]{6})\.[0-9]{4}$
```

and if you want to know if the date really exists, capture it and test it with `DateTime.TryParse` method.

Comment: `\d` does only match ASCII if you enable ECMA: `var rex = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.ECMAScript);` http://stackoverflow.com/a/16622773/360211

Answer (score 1):

> As mentioned I'm using this as an opportunity to learn Regex and felt this was a good starting point.

It's certainly not trivial to validate a date using a regular expression, particularly given the complex rules involved for leap years.  But it is possible.

The below expression will match if a valid date is input in YYYYMMdd format:

```
(?=\p{IsBasicLatin}{8}) # ensures \d matches only 0-9
(?!0000)\d{4} # year any 4-digit year, except 00
(?:0[1-9]\d|1[012]) # month 01-12
(?: 
   # day logic for leap years
   (?:
      (!00)[012]\d # Days 01-29 (we exclude 2/29 later)
      | (?<!02)30  # Day 30 valid for all months except Feb
      | (?<=0[13578]|1[02])31 # Day 31 valid for some months
   )
   # Non-Leap-year logic.  Do not allow 2/29 if the provided year
   # is not a leap year.
   (?<!
     (?:
        [13579] # years ending with odd number are not leap years
        | [02468][26]|[13579][048] # years not divisible by 4
                                     # are not leap years (02, 06, 10, ...)
        | (?:[02468][\d-[048]]|[13579][\d-[26]])00 # years divisible by
                                                 # 100 are not leap years,
                                                 # unless divisible by 400

     )0229)
)
```

Compile with `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace`.  You can use `^T~\.\d{4}$` to match the full string in your example, replacing `~` with the above expression.